# How Point-to-Point encryption eliminates PAN storing?

Tags: pci-dss

Encrypted Primary Account Numbers (PAN) are stored without any personal info. The intention is to tie it for the refunds purposes.

To move to a PCI-DSS environment, a vendor recommends moving to P2PE ([Point-to-Point Encryption](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/P2PE_v1_1_FAQs_Aug2012.pdf)) environment. This would also eliminate this requirement of storing PAN according to him.

I am wondering how the refunds will be managed then? Since the current set up permits refunds based on a relation between transaction and a PAN. Eliminating PAN how the refunds can be done?

Comment: Welcome to [security.se]. Your question cannot be answer without more context, please edit it to clearly state in what condition you are operating and what norm/regulation you are trying to satisfy.

Comment: @max make sure you use the correct acronyms and make sure you understand the tags you use. That way, you can avoid confusion.

Comment: My first thought is to ask the vendor that suggested it. Because, from a brief bit of reading on P2PE, it appears that you won't be storing the PAN at all, the vendor will. They would handle the refunds management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P2PE usage can eliminate PAN storage, because the POS system will not have access to the cleartext card data to retain from the start.  However, if you need to run subsequent transactions on the same card, such as returns or adjustments, P2PE alone will not help you there. You need to understand from the vendor what your options are.   Their answer may be to say that you will need to contact the cardholder to re-provide the PAN for any subsequent transactions.

To address the problem in a more palatable manner than that, many solutions offer both P2PE and a tokenization feature.  Rather than keep PANs, you would store a token and use that in follow up requests.  The processor/gateway/other relevant solution provider would then swap the token for the PAN when you send them a transaction.